# Find the volume of the triangle with vertices $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(2,2)$ about the y-axis using the disks method.

Tags: calculus

Note that we can find volume of this by the disk method: $\int _{a}^{b}\pi f\left( x\right) ^{2}dx$ but I could't a function $f(x)$. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Is V rotated triangle about the y-axis? Something like cone?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki yes.

Answer (score 2):

$$V=\text{Outside}-\text{Inside}=\int_1^2\pi f(x)^2dx-\int_1^2\pi\cdot1^2dx$$
 $$=\int_1^2\pi(x^2-1)dx$$
 $$=\pi\bigg[\dfrac{x^3}3-x\bigg]_1^2=\dfrac{4\pi}3$$